# HTML audio won't play file but download works

Tags: html, audio, src

I feel like I have tried everything.

I have the following:

```
<audio controls ng-src="https://myS3routeToFile" class="w-full"></audio>
```

I have also tried the following variation:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://myS3routeToFile" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I am able to press download it does download the file correctly.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second version and add an `ogg` version of your audio file to make it complatble with all browsers.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="your_file.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="your_file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Still doesnt work and the console throws no errors :(